# Swift `rethrows` function passed as parameter causes compiler error

Tags: swift, functional-programming, swift2

In Swift 2, the following function doesn't compile, even though none of the calls in the function can throw.

```
func function1<T, U>(f: Optional<T -> U>, x: Optional<T>) -> Optional<U> {
    return f.flatMap(x.map) // Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled
}
```

This version of the function is identical to the first one (and more verbose), but it compiles.

```
func function2<T, U>(f: Optional<T -> U>, x: Optional<T>) -> Optional<U> {
    return f.flatMap { g in
        x.map(g)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

These versions are not identical and I explain why.

Suppose you have function that `rethrows` because it accepts throwing function as parameter:

```
func a(x: () throws -> ()) rethrows {
  try x()
}
```

So `a(x)` is only throws if `x()` throws.

If you have function `b` that throws:

```
func b() throws {
}
```

then you have to call `a(b)` with try:

```
try a(b)
a(b) // gives "Call can throw but is not marked with 'try'"
```

but if you pass to `a` not throwing function:

```
func c() {
}
```

then Swift compiler is smart enough to determine that `x()` in `a` function body does not actually throw and it allows to simply call `a(c)`:

```
a(c) // it's ok
```

It's because:

> The throws keyword is part of a function’s type, and nonthrowing
>   functions are subtypes of throwing functions. As a result, you can use
>   a nonthrowing function in the same places as a throwing one.

Back to your example.

`Optional.flatMap()` defined as:

```
public func flatMap<U>(@noescape f: (Wrapped) throws -> U?) rethrows -> U?
```

and in your example `f.flatMap` has type `((T -> U) throws -> U?) rethrows -> U?`.

You see that it rethrows because it accepts throwing function parameter and have to be called with `try` unless `f` has type `Wrapped -> U?` and does not throw.

`Optional.map` defined as:

```
public func map<U>(@noescape f: (Wrapped) throws -> U) rethrows -> U?
```

so `x.map` has type `(T throws -> U) rethrows -> U?`.

When you call `f.flatMap { g in x.map(g) }` compiler sees that `g` has `T -> U` type and does not throw so `x.map(g)`, `{ g in x.map(g) }` and `f.flatMap { g in x.map(g) }` are all safe and do not throw.

But when you call `f.flatMap(x.map)` all that compiler sees is that `x.map` has  `(T throws -> U) rethrows -> U?` type and can (re)throw so `f.flatMap(x.map)` is not safe and also can (re)throw and have to be called with `try`.

Comment: Whilst I am sure you are correct and I have uprooted your answer. It would be great if Swift made `x.map` and `g in x.map(g)` synonymous, since they must behave the same (the type of argument passed to `map` is always `T -> U`).

Comment: @HowardLovatt You are not quite right. The type of argument passed to `Optional.map` is `T throws -> U`. But `T -> U` is subtype of `T throws -> U` and when parameter of type `T -> U` is passed to `Optional.map` compiler knows that it will not rethrow and does not give you an error.

Comment: Are you pretty sure about `a(c)` is ok?

Comment: @AhmadF It was at the time when the answer was posted.